# How do they work when you have two graphic cards on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

I have an Asus-n552vw laptop that has two graphic cards:

```
1- intel HD graphics 530
2- nvidia Geforce GTX960m
```

And installed ubuntu 16.04.2. I don't know which graphic is in use at the moment and are they installed good or not? because when I trying to suspend, it gives me PCIe Error and I should do hard power off.

I have also Windows10 beside Ubuntu and it uses intel 530 graphic by default and it only use the nvidia 960m card when I run some softwares like solidworks.

I like to know how the Ubuntu works and how can I switch off the 960m and only use 530 on Ubuntu? Also solve the suspension problem!

Comment: You need to install proprietary drivers for the Nvidia card (Intel's drivers are already installed and in use). Then, from Nvidia X Server Settings you should be able to select which card to use (reboot needed).

Comment: The GTX 960m is much, much faster than the intel HD 530. You'll want to switch to your GTX with the steps outlined in my answer.

Comment: There is a lot of info about it here and elsewhere. Just search for Nvidia Optimus. http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/4/SLN298431/EN and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have dual GPU laptop anymore to test it, but used to, this sounds like NVIDIA Optimus (for switching between cards), on Linux this is handled by the bumblebee project.

https://bumblebee-project.org/

I believe it's in the universe/multiverse repo (universe is community maintained software, multiverse copyright restricted software). If for some reason these are not enabled on your machine (in case it complains it can't find the software), you can enable them with

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
```

To install bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic primus 
reboot
```

Now it should default to your intel gpu (for power saving reasons) on everything, to start an application with your dedicated card instead, you start it with the "optirun application-to-start" command, as in:

```
optirun blender
optirun nvidia-settings
...
```

Comment: Thank you!
How can I check which one is in use at the moment?

Comment: if you use bumblee/nvidia-optimus it should always use your integrated card, and only use the dedicated (nvidia) if you start an application with optirun. To confirm that works properly per application, get an application that shows the GPU. One i could think of would be blender, if you start it with "optirun blender" you should see the GPU in it. (File > Preferences > System > Cycles Compute Device should show you a CUDA option and your Nvidia GPU if it was started with optirun and gets access to the card).

Answer (score -2):

The GTX 960m is obviously going to be a lot faster than an Intel HD card, so you'll most likely want to switch to that. Here's how you do it

ctrl+alt+t for terminal, then copy and paste this

`sudo apt install nvidia-352`

enter your password for installation, then reboot. Your system should default to your nVidia card now.

Comment: Actually no, it shouldn't. It may but not necessarily. Please read other comments before commenting yourself or answering. And why install **an old driver that does not support GTX960M**? Please check geforce.com (or nvidia.com) before recommending any specific Nvidia driver version. Otherwise you'll be responsible for some users not being able to boot at all.